# Wordpress is_home() function returns false positive for multiple post-type query

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I struggle with something which to me seems like a logic flaw from Wordpress but whether or not it is, I need a solution.
I had to modify my current setup and change almost all queries to include two post types instead of only one.

Now my query works fine, but a lot of functionality lacks because is_home() returns 1 instead of 0 on my archive page.
According to its documentation, the function should only be 1 on my blogs page

```
* If a static page is set for the front page of the site, this function will return true only
* on the page you set as the "Posts page".
```

As a matter of fact, it returns `true` although I am in a different archive than my 'Posts page' (which is Blog). If the query of that archive just holds one post_type, `is_home()`returns 0. If I add another post type to the query (which is necessary for me) `is_home()`returns `true`.

The problem is within the `query.php` file in the Wordpress core. `is_home()` returns true if, among others, `is_archive` within the query object is `false`. But `is_archive` in my case should be true (which it is not). `is_archive` would be true if `is_post_type_archive` is true (which it is not).

And thats where the problem lays:
`is_post_type_archive` is only set to true by Wordpress if

1) post_type is not an array, and

2) the post_type objects value for `has_archive` from the query is true

Both conditions don't apply for me since 1) post_type is an array, and therefore I expect 2) there is not one post type object for an array of post types and therefore has_archive cannot be true.

Long story short: I have an archive page with posts from different post_types and it does work, but these items are not my blog page and therefore, according to the docs, is_home should still be false.

Two questions: 1) is this expected behavior of is_home()? and 2) is there another function that could substitue the function and would work with my multiple-post-type-query? (if not, any suggestions on how to achieve that?)

Thanks in advance for your ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record (if anyone stumbles upon this thread with a similar issue): I worked around it by checking for `get_post_type() == 'post'` instead of `is_home()` - still not satisfying. The docs say is_home() would result in true only on the *Posts page* and it clearly does not.